# how to get the type of each value in jsonb column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query something like this where I need to find the type of each value in jsonb column

```
    id | data
     
    1  | {"uuid": "mekq1232314342134434", "size": 0}
    2  | {"uuid": "meksaq12323143421344", "size": 2}
    3  | {"uuid": "meksaq12323324421344", "size": 3}
```

The dataset looks like this but right now everything is coming as 'text'. So what can I do here?

```
select
ab_id,
data,

data->>'no_of_meals_per_day' as no_of_meals_per_day

from "postgres"."public"."_airbyte_stream"
where data ->> 'form_id' = 'base'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the`->>` operator which converts all values to strings. This makes it easier to do queries without having to worry about the type.

If you want to know what type a field is in a JSONB object you need to run `jsonb_typeof("data"->'name')`.

Comment: Hey. But this will just replace the original value with the type of the key.